# Cannot access to a script file inside docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0' 
services:
  my-db:
    build: ./Data/Docker
  my-api:
    ports: 
      - "8080:5000"         
    depends_on: 
      - my-db
   ... ommited for clarity
```

Data/Docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU17-ubuntu
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app    
COPY . /usr/src/app    
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/run-initialization.sh    
ENV SA_PASSWORD pass
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y
ENV MSSQL_PID Express    
EXPOSE 1433    
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

entrypoint.sh

```
/usr/src/app/run-initialization.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

run-initialization.sh

```
  sleep 90s        
  /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P pass -d master -i create-database.sql
```

On docker-compose up --build I'm getting the following error

```
my-db_1 | SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
my-db_1 | This container is running as user root.
my-db_1 | To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
my-db_1 | ./entrypoint.sh: line 1: /usr/src/app/run-initialization.sh: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of file is `run-initialization.sh`?  If it's a script, what's its first line?

Comment: @DavidMaze updated with run-initialization.sh content

Comment: The script doesn't have a `#!/bin/sh` line, so it's possible the system can't figure out how to run it.  Also, you're trying to start this script as a background process and then `sleep` for the main process to start; that's not really reliable, and it'd be better to run this initialization sequence from another container or from outside Docker entirely.

Answer (score 0):

As a part of the build process, inside the `Dockerfile` Add an `ls` command.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU17-ubuntu
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app    
COPY . /usr/src/app    
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/run-initialization.sh    

RUN ls -l /usr/src/app

ENV SA_PASSWORD pass
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y
ENV MSSQL_PID Express    
EXPOSE 1433    
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

This will confirm if the file exists in the first place.

Comment: ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 15: unknown instruction: LS